Elasticsearch: how to get term position in sort script
In Elasticsearch 8, I have the following index:
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "default": {
                    "type": "whitespace"
                },
                "default_search": {
                    "type": "whitespace"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "term_vector": "with_positions"
            }
        }
    }
}

And this query
{
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "banana"
        }
    },
    "track_scores": true,
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "order": "desc",
            "script": {
                "source": " >>> HOW TO GET THE POSITION OF banana IN THE title FIELD? <<< ",
                "lang": "painless"
            }
        }
    }
}

I found very old answers, such as:
_index['title'].get('banana',_POSITIONS);
But that errors:
cannot resolve symbol [_index]
I need this because I want higher score for documents where the query appears earlier in the title field.

I've explored there is no tools for getting term position in Elasticsearch (except the Analysis Predicate Context)
So my solution is to make a parallel scripted tokenizer
Sample documents
PUT /term_position_score/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"text": "apple jackfruit banana"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"text": "apple banana apple"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"text": "banana apple apple"}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"text": "nobananas apple apple"}
{"create":{"_id":5}}
{"text": "banana"}
{"create":{"_id":6}}
{"text": "banana apple"}
{"create":{"_id":7}}
{"text": "apple banana"}
{"create":{"_id":8}}
{"text": "apple jackfruit apple jackfruit apple jackfruit apple banana"}

Query with function_score and script
GET /term_position_score/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "script_score": {
                "script": {
                    "source": """
                        int getItemPosition(def array, def item) {
                            int arrayLength = array.length;
                            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                                if (item == array[i]) {
                                    return i;
                                }
                            }
                            return -1;
                        }

                        String term = params['query'];
                        String[] terms = /\s/.split(params['_source']['text']);
                        int termCount = terms.length;
                        int termPosition = getItemPosition(terms, term);
                        
                        double correctedScore = (termPosition == -1) ? 0 : (5 - Math.log(termPosition + termCount * 2));
                        return correctedScore;
                    """,
                    "params": {
                        "query": "banana"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "term_position_score",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "5",
                "_score" : 4.306853,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "banana"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "term_position_score",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "6",
                "_score" : 3.6137056,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "banana apple"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "term_position_score",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "7",
                "_score" : 3.390562,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "apple banana"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "term_position_score",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "3",
                "_score" : 3.2082405,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "banana apple apple"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "term_position_score",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 3.0540898,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "apple banana apple"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "term_position_score",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 2.9205585,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "apple jackfruit banana"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "term_position_score",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "8",
                "_score" : 1.8645058,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "apple jackfruit apple jackfruit apple jackfruit apple banana"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "term_position_score",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "4",
                "_score" : 0.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "nobananas apple apple"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

I've modified score function that text with less term count and found term position has bigger score
Limitations

Scripted tokenizer is the /\s/ regex splitter. If you need an another tokenizer, you must change the regex
Query is defined in params of the script

You can employ a search template in this use case

use like below :
{
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "banana"
        }
    },
    "track_scores": true,
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "order": "desc",
            "script": {
                "source": """
                    int position = -1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < doc['title'].size(); i++) {
                        if (doc['title'][i] == 'banana') {
                            position = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return position;
                """,
                "lang": "painless"
            }
        }
    }
}

